# How to say idiomatically in French: “There's something about ..., what with ..., that makes me feel ...”?

Tags: expressions, anglais

I just said in conversation:

> **Il se passe un truc, entre** le parfum des roses, un manteau de nuages... **J’en ressens** une étrange nostalgie.

With this sentence construction, I wanted to say something along the lines of:

> ***There's something*** (I can't put into words) ***about*** it (this whole situation), ***what with*** the scent of roses, a blanket of clouds etc, ***that makes me feel*** strangely nostalgic.

The point here is that I'm trying to express a vague feeling that I can't put into words by enumerating a few things (as they come to mind) that evoke such emotions in me.

I wonder if the structure that I used gets the job done? How do French speakers idiomatically express this idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct translation for "there's something about..."
I understand that you want to express the feeling when something is not explainable.

But we do have some phrases we use when you're talking about your *close environment*.
Let's say that the atmosphere is tense, we would say :

> Il y a de l'électricité dans l'air.

In a more general way, you can say :

> Il y a comme un air d'été aujourd'hui.

In your case, I would translate your sentence by :

> **Avec** le parfum des roses et ce manteau de nuages, cette situation a
>   **comme un air de** nostalgie.

Comment: There is no direct translation of anything all because it is meaning that should be translated. There's something about x that [makes me feel]...can be translated and it isn't what you suggest which is merely: There is x.

Answer (score 0):

L'idée exprimé en anglais:
There's something (I can't put into words) about it (this whole situation), what with the scent of roses, a blanket of clouds etc, that makes me feel strangely nostalgic.

**Cette même idée exprimée en français**

- Il y a quelque chose (que je n'arrive pas à verbaliser) qui me vient (de cette situation), avec la senteur de roses, une (la) couverture ennuagé du ciel, qui me donne un sentiment de nostalgie.
- La situation a quelque chose qui me crée, avec la senteur de roses, etc. un sentiment nostalgique

Voilà deux façons d'exprimer l'idée en français, parmi d'autres.....