# There's something to that

Tags: expressions

Comment traduirez-vous de façon idiomatique l'expression anglaise « There's something to X » ?

Cette expression signifie que X ne semble pas être faux, comme dans cet exemple où j'ai employé un calque flagrant :

> Rick says coasting down a slope in neutral is dangerous. I wasn't sure, but then I learned that it's also illegal, so maybe **there's something to** what he says.
>
> Rick dit que descendre une pente en roue libre au point mort est dangereux. Je n'étais pas certain, mais j'ai ensuite appris que c'est aussi illégal, alors peut-être qu'**il y a quelque chose** à ce qu'il dit.

<sub>*(Cette expression n'est pas l'équivalent de [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/how-to-say-idiomatically-in-french-theres-something-about-what-with).)*</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more alternative:

> Il y a peut-être un *fond de vérité* dans ce qu'il dit.

Comment: Connaissez-vous un _semblant de vérité_ et si oui pensez-vous que ça donne la même chose ? Merci !

Comment: *Semblant de vérité* existe aussi, mais il y a une nuance différente: si je dis qu'un propos a un *fond de vérité*, cela veut dire que je suis assez d'accord avec la véracité de cet élément. Si je dis qu'il y a un *semblant de vérité*, c'est que je pense que c'est peut-être pas complètement vrai, que ce n'est vrai qu'en apparence.

Answer (score 3):

Double négation typique du français à la rescousse :

> C'est pas impossible (qu'il ait raison).

Ça correspond exactement à la description que tu recherches (« semble ne pas être faux »), ça marche dans l'exemple donné, c'est à peu près du même registre et c'est courant en français oral.

Comment: C'est pas faux! <mode Kamelot>*C'est traduire que t'as pas compris ?*</mode Kamelot> ;-)

Comment: Plus sérieusement, on pourrait aussi utiliser *"Il y a de ça"*, *il y a peut être un peu de ça dans ce qu'il raconte*

Comment: Traduire ? C'est bien ce que je fais.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un registre plus familier:

> En disant cela Rick n'est pas à côté de la plaque.

ou bien

> Ce que dit Rick n'a pas l'air déconnant.

Answer (score 0):

Comme « il y a à » implique un lieu et que pour un contenu on dit généralement « il y a dans » il faudrait « il y a quelque chose dans ce qu'il dit » ; en anglais la préposition  « to » est  très idiomatique dans ce cas particulier. Cela mis à part la phrase est du bon français.

> Rick dit que descendre une pente en roue libre au point mort est dangereux. Je n'étais pas certain, mais j'ai ensuite appris que c'est aussi illégal, et donc il y a  peut-être  quelque chose dans ce qu'il dit.

Une autre possibilité

> > Rick dit que descendre une pente en roue libre au point mort est dangereux. Je n'étais pas certain, mais j'ai ensuite appris que c'est aussi illégal, et donc il y a  peut-être  du vrai dans ce qu'il dit.

Comment: L'expression existe, mais dans ce cas là c'est pas vraiment approprié. On n'est pas en train d'essayer de trouver quelque chose d'utile ou de sensé dans ce qu'il dit.